# copy cells and insert 2 lines between data

Tags: vba, excel

I have to copy Range("A22:A40") form Sheet1 to Sheet3 and Range("A22:A40") from 
Sheet2 to Sheet3. Each data must be separated by two lines in Sheet3
this is what i did :

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A22:A40") 'A40 because i can have maximum 40 data
    Application.Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), _
          .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)).Copy _
               Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A22:A40")
End With

With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A22:A40") 'A40 because i can have maximum 40 data
    Application.Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), _
          .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)).Copy _
               Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A22:A40")
End With
```

but Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A22:A40") contains only Sheets
("Sheet2").Range("A22:A40") value .

i want to insert two lines just after and then make the second copy to Sheet3

How can i separeted them by 2 rows ?

Answer (score 0):

Since both of the destination is set as **Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A22:A40")**

You are writing over First one with second one.

Try changing second destination to **Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A43:A61")**

which will leave two rows between them

Comment: i want to copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A22:A40") to Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A22:A40") and then add two lines before the second copy (i want to separate the two copy in Sheet3 by 2 rows)

Comment: Oops, My mistake, I've got the wrong range. That what you get for staying up till 5am :P I've updated my answer